Suspense fallback not showing with router.push in NextJS 13
I have a layout.tsx which fetches the data for the league based on the leagueId, and two different routes sharing this layout, one is fixtures and the other is standings. The layout.tsx also has a dropdown which lists different seasons for a league and if any of the season is selected then the fixtures/standings data will be re-fetched for that particular season.
My layout.tsx file:
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  params: { leagueId: string };
};

const LeagueLayout = async ({ children, params }: Props) => {
  const leagueId = parseInt(params.leagueId);

  const data = await getLeagueById<League<Seasons[]>>(leagueId, "baseball");

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(data.error);
  }

  if (data.success) {
    const season =
      data.success.seasons?.[data.success.seasons?.length - 1]?.season;

    const seasonList = getSeasonsList(data.success.seasons);

    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col h-screen font-sans">
        <div className="sticky top-0 z-20 flex flex-col gap-3 p-3 pb-0 shadow-sm lg:gap-6 lg:p-6 lg:pb-0 bg-background">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2 py-2 lg:gap-4">
            <ImageWithFallback
              className="w-[40px] lg:w-[50px]"
              src={data.success.logo}
              alt={`${data.success.name}-logo`}
            />
            <h2 className="flex items-center text-lg font-medium lg:text-2xl">
              {data.success.name}
              <span className="text-sm hidden lg:inline-block  lg:text-[1rem] ml-3 text-secondary-foreground">
                ({season})
              </span>
            </h2>
            <div className="hidden ml-auto lg:block">
              <DropDown
                title="seasons"
                data={seasonList}
                value={season}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">{children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default LeagueLayout;

My dropdown in which I am updating the query params with the season selected
type Props = {
  title: string;
  data?: string[];
  value: string;
  variant?: ButtonVariants;
};

export function DropDown({ title, data, value, variant }: Props) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(value);
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleValueChange = (e: string) => {
    setItem(e);
    router.push(`/baseball/league/1/fixtures?season=${e}`, {
      scroll: false,
    });
  };

  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          className="capitalize w-[130px] shadow-sm overflow-hidden"
          variant={variant ?? "outline"}
        >
          {title}
        </Button>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent className="max-h-[200px] overflow-y-auto w-[130px]">
        <DropdownMenuRadioGroup
          value={item}
          onValueChange={(e) => handleValueChange(e)}
        >
          {data?.map((v, index) => (
            <DropdownMenuRadioItem
              className="font-sans font-medium text-center capitalize"
              key={index}
              value={v}
            >
              {v}
            </DropdownMenuRadioItem>
          ))}
        </DropdownMenuRadioGroup>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

I am updating the URL with query params, so that the data for the fixtures for that particular season is fetched and rendered.
I saw a possible solution to this issue in GitHub stating that I need to add a key to the Suspense, even after making that change, it doesn't seem to work.
When the page is rendered the first time, it shows the fallback but when the URL is updated with the season, even though the data is being fetched for the new season, the fallback doesn't render.
Is there any error with my approach?
type Props = {
  searchParams: {
    season?: string;
  };
  params: {
    leagueId: string;
  };
};

const Page = async ({ searchParams, params }: Props) => {
  const season = searchParams.season || "2024";
  const leagueId = parseInt(params.leagueId);

  const key = JSON.stringify({ ...searchParams });

  const data = await getFixturesByLeagueId(leagueId, season, "baseball");

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(data.error);
  }

  if (data.success) {
    return (
      <Suspense key={key} fallback={<Loading />}>
        <div className="w-full h-full bg-red-600">FIXTURES</div>
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
};

export default Page;


It might be the node wrapped around by Suspense is static, so it only trigger by the first render, if you want the loading state before whole page, try adding loading.tsx at the same level of page.
